# Replace parts of query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Say I have a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/dir1/dir2/index.php?Part1Part2Part3
```

How would I be able to do a simple string replace to replace the parts within .htaccess? For example, I want to change it like so

```
Part1 -> Part4
Part2 -> Part5
Part3 -> Part6
```

Which would result in the URL actually being

```
http://example.com/dir1/dir2/index.php?Part4Part5Part6
```

Comment: Are `Part1Part2Part3` always together contiguously as shown in example?

Comment: @anubhava no, it could be possible that they can appear as `Part3Part1Part2` which is why I was hoping I could have each replaced individually rather than that entire query string

Comment: Are these string always part of a query string?

Comment: @anubhava Yes! While the order varies they will always be part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules for replacing multiple strings from query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*?)Part1(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1Part4%2 [E=redir:1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*?)Part2(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1Part5%2 [E=redir:1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*?)Part3(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1Part6%2 [E=redir:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:redir} =1
RewriteRule .* /$0 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more thing, would it be possible to get them replaced in a non-redirection style similar to how short links work?

Comment: Yes, you can remove R=301 flag from last rule and it will be silent rewrite then.

Answer (score -1):

Guide for replacing strings in coding editor

1. Alt+F= find
2. type Part1Part2Part3 in search box
3. Alt+R=replace
4. type Part4Part5Part6 in replace box

Source: My noob self. Take with a grain of salt.