# htaccess replace string from parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to replace any value of the `ref` parameter that starts with `0x` in `aaa`.
I want to do this in `.htaccess`

I have links like this:
`domain/test.php?ref=0x1234` or `domain/test.php?ref=0xABC`

and I want to change them to:
`domain/test.php?ref=aaa`.

I want to use the value of the parameter `ref` in php, but I don't want to use the initial value `0x...`, I want to use the value modified by htaccess `aaa`

```
<?php
echo $_GET['ref']
?>
```

Result my code: `aaa`

Comment: not clear what you're saying.

Comment: Do you want every possibly value of `ref=` to result in `aaa` in PHP, or only those two? Also, do you want to redirect or just remap?

Comment: Your examples show a parameter called "ref". Then suddenly you say something about a parameter "id". Sorry, but this sounds confused and confusing, it is not possible to answer to such a question. Please invest time into revising your question. There is an "edit" link below it, _use it_ ... You need to be _precise_ in your question.

Comment: @Criss Hass I want to remap for any value that starts with 0x

Comment: I generally steer people away from putting such rules in htaccess because it is very easy to forget about, especially with new team members. Instead, this feels like it could easily be done in PHP where it is easier to document: https://3v4l.org/g8MuO

Comment: My project has more than 2000 php files, it is not a solution to add php code in each php file. I made a php script that replaces the value from `ref` and I included it in htaccess via: `php_value include_path` or `php_value auto_prepend_file`  but the php script does not run

Comment: If you have a simple structure and there's only one query string key and/or it is in a known order, you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974925/231316. If you have multiple query string values you might be able to use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877271/231316. I unfortunately don't use Apache anymore so I'm not as familiar as I once was.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with the help of the post from the link: [Replace parts of query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876249/replace-parts-of-query-string/47877271#47877271)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*=)0x(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1aaa%2 [L]

for result: aaa1234

or

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*=)0x [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1aaa%2 [L]

for result: aaa
```

@Criss Hass thank you, your recommendations helped me to solve my problem.